# How can I write the linear scheme in the signal processing system tool?

Tags: draw, tikz-graphdrawing

Hello Tex friends I am trying to draw the linear scheme for the signal processing tool. I am testing the Signal processing library. However, I can not get the figure like that.

This library:

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/noise-shaper/

If you have any ideas, please let me know.

[image]

Comment: You seem to have tried making the diagram, so why not show us the code you have already, that way we might only need to fill in the blanks, instead of making the whole thing from scratch. (There is no "signal processing library" in that link, by the way.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from the example in the link it is not too difficult to draw these things. Believe me, it is much more fun to try out yourself.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta,calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  block/.style    = {rectangle, minimum height = 3em,    minimum width = 3em,draw,fill=white},
  sum/.style      = {circle,draw,fill=white},
  forward/.style  = {isosceles triangle,draw,fill=white},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,auto, thick, node distance=2cm, >={Triangle},font=\sffamily]
% upper branch
\draw (0,0) coordinate(L1) node[above right] {$x_1(t)$} 
-- ++ (2,0) node[right,forward](a1){$a_1$} ;
\draw (a1) -- ++ (2.5,0)
node[midway,above] {$a_1\,x_1(t)$}
 -- ++ (1,-1) node[below right,sum] (s1){$+$};
% lower branch (using calc to make it symmetric)
\draw let \p1=($(L1)-(s1)$) in ([yshift=-2*\y1]L1) coordinate(L2)
node[above right] {$x_2(t)$}
-- ++ (2,0) node[right,forward] (a2){$a_2$};
\draw (a2) -- ++ (2.5,0) 
node[midway,above] {$a_2\,x_2(t)$}
-- (s1);
% joint branch
\draw (s1) -- ++(4,0) node[right,block]{$\mathcal{H}$}
node[midway,above] {$a_1\,x_1(t)+a_2\,x_2(t)$} -- ++(3,0)
node[above] {$\mathcal{H}\{a_1\,x_1(t)+a_2\,x_2(t)\}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,auto, thick, node distance=2cm, >={Triangle},font=\sffamily]
% upper branch
\draw (0,0) coordinate(L1) node[above right] {$x_1(t)$} -- 
++ (2,0) node[block,right] (H1) {$\mathcal{H}$}; 
\draw (H1) -- ++ (3,0) node[midway,above]{$\mathcal{H}\{x_1(t)\}$} 
node[right,forward](a1){$a_1$} ;
\draw (a1) -- ++ (3,0)
node[midway,above] {$a_1\,\mathcal{H}\{x_1(t)\}$}
 -- ++ (1,-1) node[below right,sum] (s1){$+$};
% lower branch (using calc to make it symmetric)
\draw let \p1=($(L1)-(s1)$) in ([yshift=-2*\y1]L1) coordinate(L2)
node[above right] {$x_2(t)$} -- 
++ (2,0) node[block,right] (H2) {$\mathcal{H}$}; 
\draw (H2) -- ++ (3,0) node[midway,above]{$\mathcal{H}\{x_2(t)\}$} 
node[right,forward](a2){$a_2$} ;
\draw (a2) -- ++ (3,0)
node[midway,above] {$a_2\,\mathcal{H}\{x_1(t)\}$} -- (s1);
% joint branch
\draw (s1) -- ++(3,0)
node[above] {$a_1\,\mathcal{H}\{x_1(t)\}+a_2\,\mathcal{H}\{x_2(t)\}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hi, is it possible to split the line into multiple lines? I just want to write multi-lines text. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user3727281 Yes. you need to add some `text width` or align option. Try e.g. `node[right,block,align=center]{$\mathcal{H}$\\ $XYZ$}`.